# Vous recevrez un email avec votre « numéro de suivi » ou « numéro de repérage » ?

Tags: vocabulaire, choix-de-mot, commerce

Une fois qu'un client a passé une commande avec moi, il reçoit une confirmation par e-mail à propos de sa commande ainsi que son numéro de commande.

Ils reçoit également un e-mail avec le numéro de [...?] pour son modem mais je ne sais pas s'il faut dire « numéro de **suivi** » ou « numéro de **repérage** ».

Comment: Je le savais et je vous remercie! Je suppose que je tapais si vite que je pas l'ai remarqué la façon que je l'ai écrit jusqu'à maintenant :)

Answer (score 1):

« Numéro de suivi » est couramment utilisé en France pour permettre à un client de suivre l'acheminement d'un colis par un transporteur. « Numéro de repérage » semble être l'équivalent au Québec.

Comment: Je suis définitivement pas habitué à dire: "numéro de suivi" mais maintenant il est logique! Donc, Il est juste une question culturel

Comment: Qc on accepte les [deux](http://granddictionnaire.com/ficheOqlf.aspx?Id_Fiche=26529776), mais [postescanada](https://www.canadapost.ca/web/fr/home.page) utilise # de _repérage_ alors que [Termium](http://www.btb.termiumplus.gc.ca/tpv2alpha/alpha-eng.html?lang=eng&i=1&srchtxt=TRACKING+NUMBER&index=alt&codom2nd_wet=1#resultrecs) n'aborde pas le concept. Typique.

Answer (score 0):

Repérage ne s'emploie en France que dans le sens de *repérer* (sic), pour *préparer*, **avant** de faire autre chose: film, tournage, toutes sortes d'opérations (spectacle, randonnée), licites ou délictueuses (cambriolage ...).

On trouve couramment:

- *numéro de commande*;
- *numéro de suivi*;
- *numéro de référence*, ou plus simplement *référence*, ou référence de *commande*, de *suivi*, d'*acheminement*, de *routage* (plus technique);
- *identifiant* (de commande, ...);
- *code* (de commande, ...);

Comment: Un repérage, c'est l'action de placer des repères, rien n'impose qu'un repérage soit terminé avant que l'on puisse commencer à l'appeler un repérage. Il n'est donc pas illégitime d'utiliser ce terme pour désigner la localisation dans le temps et dans l'espace des étapes de la prise en compte d'une commande comme son emballage, son expédition, son routage et sa livraison. Ce n'est simplement pas une habitude en France.

Comment: @jlliagre d'accord pour cette définition académique, mais on ne l'emploie pas ainsi en France, j'ai donc modifié ma demande.